# How to turn a LED-Strip off after if condition

Tags: led, esp32

\

I'm working on code have that simulate Knight rider leds. I want to control Led via bluetooth as i can switch off.
but i tried several things but doesn't work .
any help.
*/I'm working on code have that simulate Knight rider leds. I want to control Led via bluetooth as i can switch off.
but i tried several things but doesn't work .
any help

code:

```cpp
#include "BluetoothSerial.h" 
#include <Adafruit_NeoPixel.h>
#define N_LEDS 8
#define PIN    23
Adafruit_NeoPixel strip = Adafruit_NeoPixel(N_LEDS, PIN, NEO_GRB + 
NEO_KHZ800);

BluetoothSerial ESP_BT; 
int incoming;
int r;
int pos = 0, dir = 1; 

void setup() {
    strip.begin();
    Serial.begin(9600); 
    ESP_BT.begin("ESP32_LED_Control"); 
    Serial.println("Bluetooth Device is Ready to Pair");
}

void loop() {

    strip.setPixelColor(pos - 2, 0x100000); // Dark red
    strip.setPixelColor(pos - 1, 0x800000); // Medium red
    strip.setPixelColor(pos    , 0xFF3000); // Center pixel is brightest
    strip.setPixelColor(pos + 1, 0x800000); // Medium red
    strip.setPixelColor(pos + 2, 0x100000); // Dark red
    strip.show();
    delay(85);   // control speed

    for (r=-2; r<= 2; r++) strip.setPixelColor(pos+r, 0);

    pos += dir;
    if (pos < 0) {
        pos = 1;
        dir = -dir;
    } else if (pos >= strip.numPixels()) {
        pos = strip.numPixels() - 2;
        dir = -dir;
    }

    if (ESP_BT.available()) //Check if we receive anything from Bluetooth
    {
        incoming = ESP_BT.read(); //Read what we recevive 
        Serial.print("Received:"); Serial.println(incoming);
    }  

    if (incoming == 48)
    {
        //Should put here code that works on stop strip led//
        ESP_BT.println("LED turned OFF");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To turn off all LEDs I would do something like:

```cpp
/**
* Turn off all LEDs
*/
void allBlack()
{
  for (uint16_t indexPixel = 0; indexPixel < N_LEDS; indexPixel++)
  {
     strip.SetPixelColor(indexPixel, 0x000000);
  }
  strip.show();
}
```

I know is maybe not the scope of this question, but I recommend to test this library:

https://github.com/Makuna/NeoPixelBus
Since it has a lot of good examples and it would be in my opinion a lot better not to use delay but give a certain time like it's shown on Makuna examples to have more control over the animation. 
I also have another animation examples in this [small project that is triggered by UDP commands](https://github.com/martinberlin/Remora).

Comment: Thx Kentaro Okuda ..i'll check that